# how to revert changes to a specific version in Source Control?

Tags: version-control, ssas, ssas-tabular

I want to revert my .bim file back to changeset 13900.

If I right click 13900 and hit 'Rollback entire changeset', will I obtain the desired result?

[image]

What isn't clear is that 'Rollback entire changeset' can mean 'Rollback 13900 entire changeset' which means it would go to a previous version than 13900

Answer (score 0):

As I assumed you use Visual Studio.

1. View the history of the thing you want to rollback.
2. Select the changeset you want to roll back.
3. Right click on the changset and choose "Rollback".
4. Check that the pending changes are correct (the rollback command will revert the entire changeset not just the file you selected)
5. Check in.

Comment: My problem is with point 2. Do I select the changeset I want to 'undo'? or do I select the changeset that I want to 'rollback to'?

Comment: jest select the changeset that want you to "rollback to"